# How to enable the write permission on web directory?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, doc, user-permissions

I am writing an application which is daemon. It operates on a web-directory which is inside the `inetpub/wwwroot/daemon_Folder`. It will change the files there. The problem is that the folder manages to prevent the application from writing on it. I changed the permissions by right clicking it `properties Window => Web sharing => Share this folder` => then selecting the write permission and executables. I even changed the permission in `Control Panel=>Administarative Tools=>IIS=>websites=>that_Folder=>permissions`. But still I am getting `"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."` when I tried to save doc file programmatically. Can anybody say how to achieve this?

Note: I am using windows-XP, iis v5.1,visual studio 2010,office 2010, .net 4.0,c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Attempted to read or write protected memory' - this is not a folder permissions/privileges problem, it is a variation on 'Access Violation' - your code is trying to access unmanaged memory when/where it should not:(

Comment: Your answer is letting me to approach the center of the error. I am checking on it. And it seems true.

Comment: Bull's eye. You are correct. The core of the problem is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.SaveAs2 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word v14.0.0.0). I am going to ask about this in some other thread.

Comment: Oh look!  A M$ Word automation bug.  What a surprise!  <g>

Comment: I can't get you. Is it a direct comment or a sarcasm.

Comment: It's sarcasm - I've suffered from Word automation myself, so I understand your pain <g>  Likewise, Excel automation:((